# Prove that $\Omega$ equals the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\Sigma,S)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-sets

I'm solving problems from my Functional Analysis course and I don't know how to prove one of the implications of this exercise:

> Given $(X,\Sigma)$ a measure space and given $S\subset X$. Consider
> $\Omega\subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ defined as $$\Omega = \left\{ C\subset
>  X\mid \exists A,B\in\Sigma \text{ s.t. }C=(A\cap S)\cup(B\cap
>  S^c)\right\}.$$ Prove that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\Sigma$
> and $S$ (I'll denote it $\sigma(\Sigma,S)$) equals $\Omega$.

I've tried proving that $\sigma(\Sigma,S)$ contains $\Omega$ and viceversa:

- $\subseteq$ : This one was easy. Assume $E\in\Omega$, then $E=(A\cap S)\cup(B\cap
   S^c)$ for some $A,B\in\Sigma$. Since $\sigma$-algebras are closed by countable unions and intersections, it is so by finite unions and intersections; and also closed by complements, and clearly $A,B,S,S^c\in\sigma(\Sigma, S)$ so necessarily $(A\cap S)\cup(B\cap
   S^c)=E\in\sigma(\Sigma,S)$ and this gives as that $\Omega\subseteq\sigma(\Sigma,S)$.
- $\supseteq$ : This is the one I don't know how to approach. I assume $E\in\sigma(\Sigma,S)$, but then I don't know how to prove it is implied that $E\in\Omega$. I've considered assuming $E\notin\Omega$ and see if I get a contradiction, but I get lost again. How can I prove this one? Is the raw definition of $\sigma$-algebra needed to do this?

Is my approach to the first contain correct? How can I prove the second one? Any help or hint will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: You have to first verify that $\Omega$ is  a $\sigma-$ algebra. Then  observe that it contains  $\Sigma$ and the set $S$. It follows that it contains $\sigma (\Sigma, S)$.

Comment: That makes sense! I think I can easily prove that $\Omega$ is a sigma algebra, and since $\sigma(\Sigma,S)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains both $\Sigma$ and $S$, then it's necessarily contained inside $\Omega$. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've achieved a solution following your tip. Should I edit my question to add at the end the prove I came up with?